list of labels in a separate file out of input files included in a main file
I was trying this amazing solution displayed for the question
Can I get a list of labels written to a separate file, or at least in one place in the document?
in a project file (main with several attached included files, commands \include{includedfile} present). It did not work. I am sincere in saying it amazing, cause it indeed work on article documents. However, not whenever you need to include files with \include.
Is there a workaround for that?
How can you make the list of the used labels in a project that is a main file with its included files where labels are spread out the included files (not explicitly appearing in the main document)?

I don't see any reason why that wouldn't work with \include. If you get an error please post a small test document and test included file and show what error you get.

personally if I wanted this, I wouldn't use tex to make the list at all I'd just do grep -o '\\newlabel{[^{}]*}' *.aux and get a list of all labels in all aux files in the currnt directory.

Thank you David, I worked in some other way (change the original goal), but I appreciated your advice
